# Run Autocad exe and load script file error

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

This is My first post in here 
I need a help for your side I have made a batch file for run autocad exe and load a script file but give error when I run the batch file

```
    @echo off

set KEY_NAME=HKCU\Software\Laxman Enterprises\Xpresslisp Tools
set VALUE_NAME=installpath
set FN=loadload
set FE=scr

FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG.exe query "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%"') DO (set pInstallDir=%%B)
set approot=%pInstallDir:~0,-1%
echo %approot%\%FN%.%FE%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe"  /b  %approot%\%FN%.%FE%
pause
```

Error: while running batch file autocad opens and in commandline the script file not loading "Xpresslisp.scr": Can't find file."

and bellow one is working 
script file loading without getting error

```
@echo off
set path=%USERPROFILE%
set fol=Documents
set NAME=1
set SUFFIX=scr
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe"  /b  %path%\%fol%\%NAME%.%SUFFIX%
pause
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error message that you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question in the comments...

Bellow command will create the text file and write the first line to it e.g. "some text" like in the command below.

```
Echo some text > full_path_to_txt_file
```

Command below will append new text to same file.

```
Echo some text >> full_path_to_txt_file
```

'>' char creates file and writes firs line
'>>' char  append text

Comment: YanivK  How to add two Value for example have path variable   "%approot%\%FN%.%FE%"  and want to combine with (load "%approot%\%FN%.%FE%") =  (load "C:\Xpresslisp Tools\loadload.scr" )

Comment: Combine into what ? Like new variable that contain the full execution command?

Answer (score 0):

check that `%path%\%fol%\%NAME%.%SUFFIX%` returns the Full Path to the "Xpresslisp.scr" file !

if it does, inspect the Full Path and see if it contains any white spaces.

if it does, enclose the `%path%\%fol%\%NAME%.%SUFFIX%` with apostrophes

```
"%path%\%fol%\%NAME%.%SUFFIX%"
```

Comment: Wow many many thanks YanivK it is working now added Quote as you said its load the script file where file is located

Comment: Also i suggest that you start using PowerShell, it's so much better in many ways :)

Comment: thank you sir, i need one more favor Ctrl+K not working for post codes in comment section any suggestion please

Comment: YanivK I want to create a text file and write few line and save close it  please guide me how to do that

Comment: Wrote as answer

Answer (score 0):

It may be something as simple as blindly removing the last character of the `installpath` without knowing for sure what it is, *(doublequote or backslash?)*.

As there is unlikely to be multiple copies of any filename in the `Xpresslisp Tools` tree, I would suggest something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "KEY_NAME=HKCU\Software\Laxman Enterprises\Xpresslisp Tools"
Set "VALUE_NAME=installpath"
Set "FN=loadload"
Set "FE=scr"

(Echo=FILEDIA 0
Echo=(LOAD "C:\\loadmyfile.lsp"^)
Echo=FILEDIA 1)>%FN%.%FE%

For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%"') Do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%C In ('Dir/B/S/A-D "%%~B"\"%FN%.%FE%" 2^>Nul') Do (
        Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" /b  "%%~C"))
```

This doesn't care if there is a trailing backslash or not and will only run the AutoCAD command if the file is there.

Comment: Compo after change few line codes working properly  thank you so much

Comment: The only lines you should have changed, based on the comment above was line 5, _(which I only changed from your actual code due to your provided error message)_. I have changed it back in my answer above; do not change anything else, _there is no need to change the AutoCAD path_.

Comment: yes i have  changed only one line  sorry i did not noticed

Comment: Hi compo I need one more favor  in my script file I want to write  the following code 1.line "filedia 0"  2.line " (load "C:\\loadmyfile.lsp") " 3.line "filedia 1"and save it

Comment: I have added the code you have requested in lines 8-10, writing it to loadload.scr, (closing parentheses in the scr file need escaping). Please bear in mind that you're asking me for updates on my code when you gave someone else the points etc. marking their answer as correct.